# ANDROID moving from view to another activity

Tags: android, events, view, android-activity, touch

(I have got class MainActivity (extends Activity) and there I have got method setContentView(GameView); 
GameView is a class which extends View and in this class (GameView) I have got method:

```
boolean inTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
switch(event.getAction()){
case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
//here I would like to go to another activity to class MainMenuActivity()
}
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Ok it's work:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){ 
    switch(event.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:   
        Intent intent = new Intent (contexTmp, MainActivity.class);
        contexTmp.startActivity(intent);
        ((Activity)getContext()).finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: Serious? Do you even know that documentation exists? Why clog up SO with this question... one Google search could tell you this 100 times over. Please visit the docs here: http://developer.android.com/develop/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To go to another activity:

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, MainMenuActivity.class);
context.startActivity(i);
```

Comment: context should be of Activity class.

Answer (score 0):

Do as follows:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), MainMenuActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: View class doesn't have `startActivity()` method.

Comment: change it to context.startActivity(intent);

Answer (score 0):

Since you are in the same activity can set back the mainmenu view using `setContentView(main);`

If you need to go back to your Main menu activity from a different activity, you need this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), MainMenuActivity.class);
intent.setFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: View class doesn't have `startActivity()` method.

Comment: You can set back the mainmenu view using `setContentView(main);` dont use above  code..

Answer (score -1):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(presentActivity.this, MainMenuActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```